# Return a string from Win32 RPC call

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, rpc

I'm trying to make an RPC call which requests 2 numbers and a string from the RPC server, the IDL looks like this:

```
void GetCurrentStatus([in] handle_t hBinding, [out, ref] DWORD *dwRef1, [out, ref] DWORD *dwRef2, UINT *nLength, [out, size_is(, *nLength)] LPWSTR *pszName);
```

In the server-side call I do this:

```
// name = std::wstring
*pszName = (wchar_t*)midl_user_allocate(name.length()+1 * sizeof(wchar_t));
_tcscpy(*pszName, name.c_str());
*nLength = name.length();
```

But any attempt to call from the client-side results in nothing returned the error `The array bounds are invalid.`

What is the correct way to return a string from an RPC call?

Thanks,
J

Comment: Does the error occur during the call or the return?  i.e. does `GetCurrentStatus` actually execute server-side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a choice in the matter, use `BSTR` (i.e. `SysAllocString`).  RPC knows all about this data type and how to copy it and find its length.

Just

```
[out, retval] BSTR* pstrName
```

is enough, no separate length parameter needed.

Comment: I could use BSTR I suppose but I'd rather understand what I'm doing wrong so I can avoid problems like this in future.

Comment: @JWood: RPC assumes a caller-provided buffer.  `[out]` simply means the data will not be copied in the forward direction.  I think the way to pass an array of `wchar_t` would be `[in, out] UINT* nLength, [out, size_is(*nLength)] LPWSTR szName` (note it's not a double pointer), but I'm out of practice with DCOM.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367164.aspx  I'm not sure exactly what you've done wrong.

Comment: Using SAFEARRAY would also be a viable option.

Comment: Voight - You were absoloutely right, I was expecting to be able to allocate the memory on the server-side and return the size to the caller which thinking about it doesn't make sense. Creating a fixed buffer and sending the size from the client solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The server is not able to pass string value back to client since it doesn't know how to marshall the string..

When you use  BSTR type, the server knows to the length of the string. BSTR must be preceded by a 4-byte length field and terminated by a single null 2-byte character.

Answer (score -1):

Where you have written:

```
*nLength = name.length();
```

I believe you need

```
*nLength = (name.length() + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR);
```

In particular, if you have an empty (length zero) string, then returning a `size_is(0)` array is not legal -- so you must add space for the string-terminating NUL (`L'\0'`).

You also want to supply the size in bytes, where each Unicode character uses two bytes -- therefore you must multiply by the character size.

Comment: Absolutely not.  `size_is` "represents the allocation size, in **elements**".  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367164.aspx

Comment: Good point.  He was still missing the +1 for the \0, and I support his desire to do this manually, rather than using a BSTR.